# Проверка стартовых данных при создании объекта

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток, как проверить входящие данные при создании объекта, например у меня есть объект Rectangle, в нём параметры конструктора координаты вершин, и при создании объекта не должны быть на одной прямой, как правильно сделать? Проверять данные до начала объекта, больше всего логичнее, но а может как-то можно при создании объекта проверить?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
// проверка?
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(1,2, 3,4, 6,5, 4,3);
    }
}

public class Rectangle{
    public Rectangle(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double x3, double y3, double x4, double y4) {
    // проверка?
    }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Легко, кинуть Exception:

```
public class Rectangle{
     public Rectangle(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, 
                      double x3, double y3, double x4, double y4) {
          boolean ok = false;
          // проверка
          // ...
          if(!ok)
               throw new RectangleException();
     }

     // для быстроты пусть будет статик
     public static class RectangleException extends Exception {
     // ...
     }
 }
```

Добавил main для наглядности:

```
public class Main {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
          // проверка
          Rectangle rect = null;
          try {
               rect = new Rectangle(1,2, 3,4, 6,5, 4,3);
          } catch(RectangleException ex) {
               // обработать исключение
          }
          // далее rect будет null если конструктор Rectangle не прошел проверку
     }
}
```

Comment: То есть объект не создастся, если не пройдёт if(!ok) ? Он же уже вроде создан ещё в main классе?

Comment: Конструктор не создаст объект если конструктор объекта кинет исключение. На то исключения и придумали. А переменную "ok" я выдумал для наглядности. Суть в выражении throw new RectangleException()

Comment: Я не знал, спасибо огромное, не дошёл в изучении языка до исключений.

Answer (score 1):

добавлять какую-либо логику в конструктор не очень хорошая идея, потому что конструктор создан для инициализации обьекта, и может случится так что инициализация обьекта еще не закончена, а вы уже вызвали валидацию (часто бывает если имеется наследование).

Если все же нужно добавить какую-то логику для проверки используют шаблоны программирования (factory method, abstract factory, builder).

в вашем случае имеет смысл использовать `factory method` - добавляется статический метод который служит для создания этого обьекта и конструктор обьекта делается приватным (для того чтоб "умники" не создавали обьект в обход этого метода):

```
import java.text.MessageFormat;

public class Rectangle {

    private static final String ERROR_MSG = "Points are on the same line, points : {0}, {1}, {2}";

    public static Rectangle valueOf(Point a, Point b, Point c, Point d) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        // create new rectangle
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
        rectangle.setA(a);
        rectangle.setB(b);
        rectangle.setC(c);
        rectangle.setD(d);
        rectangle.validate(); // throws an exception if rectangle is not valid one

        return rectangle;
    }

    private Point a;
    private Point b;
    private Point c;
    private Point d;

    private Rectangle() {
    }

    public Point getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public Point getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public Point getC() {
        return c;
    }

    public Point getD() {
        return d;
    }

    public void setA(Point a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public void setB(Point b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public void setC(Point c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public void setD(Point d) {
        this.d = d;
    }

    protected void validate() {
        validate(a, b, c);
        validate(a, b, d);
        validate(a, c, d);
    }

    /**
     * Check if 3 points are belong to the same line
     * 
     * @param a1
     * @param a2
     * @param a3
     */
    protected void validate(Point a1, Point a2, Point a3) {
        // nothing to validate
        if (null == a1 || null == a2 || null == a3) {
            return;
        }

        // ensure the same point is not provided twice
        boolean valid = (a1 != a2 && a2 != a3 && a1 != a3);

        // ensure points are not placed on the line
        valid = valid && validateLine(a1, a2, a3);

        // throw error if needed
        if (false == valid) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(MessageFormat.format(ERROR_MSG, a1, a2, a3));
        }
    }

    private boolean validateLine(Point a1, Point a2, Point a3) {
        // TODO: throw error if points are on the same line
        return false;
    }
}
```

класс `Point` который используется для хранения координат обычный POJO bean:

```
public class Point {

    private int x;
    private int y;

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```